# How to avoid "request entity too large" error?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a rather large series of cypher query. Some 700 rows of code like this:

```
CREATE (:System {name: "Game.Zones.CellCheckSystem", componentTypes: ["Game.Zones.Block", "Game.Common.Owner", "Game.Objects.Transform", "Game.Net.EdgeGeometry", "Game.Net.StartNodeGeometry", "Game.Net.EndNodeGeometry", "Game.Net.Composition", "Game.Prefabs.PrefabRef", "Game.Prefabs.NetCompositionData", "Game.Prefabs.RoadComposition", "Game.Prefabs.AreaGeometryData", "Game.Prefabs.ObjectGeometryData", "Game.Common.Native", "Game.Zones.ValidArea", "Game.Zones.ValidArea", "Game.Net.BuildOrder", "Game.Prefabs.SpawnableBuildingData", "Game.Prefabs.SignatureBuildingData", "Game.Prefabs.PlaceholderBuildingData", "Game.Prefabs.ZoneData", "Game.Common.Updated"]})
CREATE (:System {name: "Game.Zones.LoadSystem", componentTypes: []})
CREATE (:System {name: "Game.Zones.SearchSystem", componentTypes: ["Game.Zones.Block", "Game.Common.Created", "Game.Common.Deleted"]})
CREATE (:System {name: "Game.Zones.UpdateCollectSystem", componentTypes: ["Game.Zones.Block", "Game.Common.Created", "Game.Common.Deleted"]})
```

When I copy it into Memgrapg Lab I get the error "Uh oh! Something unexpected went wrong. Please try again or contact Memgraph support. Details: request entity too large".

[[image: MemgraphLab(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeMod.png)]

If I copy paste 100 lines at time and I run the 7 queries then they all get executed. From this I conclude that the problem is not any of the `CREATE` queries but something else. I'd like to avoid the splitting so what can I do?

I use Memgraph 2.13 Platfor edition in Docker.

Comment: Maybe a timeout error, the smaller batches complete in time, but a large batch times out before its done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there is a limitation on the size of the query that can be written directly into Memgrpah Lab. What you can do is save your 700 queries into a file and call it something like `nodes.cypherl`. Then import that `.cypherl` file [using Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-migration/cypherl).