# Importing cypherl with relationships deltes all nodes in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb, memgraph, cypherl

Following advice from [How to avoid "request entity too large" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693171/how-to-avoid-request-entity-too-large-error/77698654) I've created two `.cypherl` files. One for nodes and one for relationships.

I've imported the nodes but when I import relationships I lose all my nodes and I see zero relationships but the query execution was ok.

This is sample of my relationships

```
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Tools.ToolSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.CitySystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.CityStatisticsSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.City.CityConfigurationSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.SimulationSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.ClimateSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.TimeSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Prefabs.PrefabSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.AchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.DeathCheckSystem"}) CREATE (a)<-[:USED_IN]-(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.EventAchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.SimulationSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Achievements.EventAchievementTriggerSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Common.ModificationEndBarrier"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaConnectionSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Common.ModificationBarrier4B"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Areas.SearchSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.NaturalResourceSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.CitySystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.TerrainSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.WaterSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.AreaResourceSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.GroundWaterSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.CurrentDistrictSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Areas.UpdateCollectSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.CurrentDistrictSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Areas.SearchSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.CurrentDistrictSystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Common.ModificationBarrier5"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.GeometrySystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.TerrainSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
MATCH (a:System {name: "Game.Areas.GeometrySystem"}), (b:System {name: "Game.Simulation.WaterSystem"}) CREATE (a)-[:USES]->(b);
```

[image]